# Nav Bar Links won't work

Tags: html, css

As the title states my links don't work in my nav bar except for the last one and they're all the same code so I'm not understanding why they won't work.

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="ulfirst">
  <li id="lithree"><a href="GCPD.html" id="athird">We work very closely with the GCPD</a></li>
  <li id="lisecond"><a href="Wayneenterprises.html" id="athird">Here is information about how we work</a> </li>
  <li id="lifour"><a href="Publicrecords.html" id="athird">Public Database</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the relating CSS:

```
#ulfirst {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#lisecond {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

#lithree {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0 ;
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: left; 
  left: 30%; 
}

#lifour {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: right; 
  right: 25%
}
```

Comment: Edit: So let me rephrase. I have a navigation bar and only the last link on the bar (always the last one, not necessarily publicrecords). The other two links don't work, as in the mouse doesn't even change when hovered over.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your goal is, but here's my code for a nav-bar, it may help:

html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
nav {
    background-color: #004b98;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 900px;
}

nav li {
    background-color: #004b98;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

nav li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #0069d4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is your index.html, GCPD.html, Wayneenterprises.html, Publicrecords.html. in one folder or not? and also you can't use #ulfirst as a class.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your links have correct capitalization, it's easy to accidentally capitalize something that's not. This sounds simple, but happens easily.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `margin: 0;` into your styles, it gives some other element space to interfere, I think.  It's all about the margins.  Create margins for your navigation, see if that helps.